# How we decide that in project we need role base user or we create every user schema like buyer seller and agent mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to create a project in which there are three types of users what should I do should go for rolebase or create three different schemas

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the usage is. Are you mostly doing reports based on the user themselves, like what is the history for a buyer, a seller, or an agent? Or are you mostly doing reports on the objects being sold, where the buyer/seller/agent might show up?

For example, let's say it's a real estate app, most of the searches will be focused on properties in a specific geographical area with specific features (e.g. properties in a neighborhood that have at least 3 bedrooms and a garage). Or even a buy/sell app like eBay, most of the searches are around the product.

Yes, people will search for their own history, or others' history (agents in a real estate app, buyer and seller ratings in a buy/sell app), but that is a small amount of traffic in comparison.

So I would set it up with an extended reference schema pattern - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-extended-reference-pattern - where the details of the user are put right into the product object....

e.g. property collection

```
{
id: ObjectId('123abc'),
address: '123 main street',
city: 'Anytown',
country: 'USA',
bedrooms: 2,
bathrooms: 1,
garage: 0,
agent: [ userId: ObjectId('789xyz'), name: 'John Doe' ]
asking price: 225000
}
```

and then a user collection might have:
{
userId: ObjectId('789xyz'),
name: 'John Doe',
agent: [ ObjectId('123abc'), ObjectId('abc123')]
}

which means that John Doe has been the agent for 2 properties. I would do it this way assuming an agent could also be a buyer or seller (not just a 'sell-by-owner' scenario, but an agent may buy or sell their own house, and use another agent to do so).

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful but how we will give the seller(company) some rights to there agent

Comment: in this schema pattern how update profile data works?